# Which of the following numbers are rationals?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let, 
$$\alpha=1+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{25}+\frac{1}{49}+\cdots$$
$$\beta=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots$$
$$\gamma=1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{25}+\cdots$$
Then which of the following are rational numbers,

1. $\frac{\alpha}{\gamma}$
2. $\frac{\beta}{\gamma}$
3. $\frac{\beta^2}{\gamma}$

Now we know that $\gamma=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, using this I've calculated the value of $\alpha$ which turns out to be $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$. Hence $1$ is correct. Now I got stuck with $\beta$. How can I calculate the sum of $\beta$? Any hint or help please.

Comment: it is the telescope

Comment: Hint: You can use the taylor series for $\arctan$

Comment: $\beta$ can be computed using the Maclaurin series for $\arctan(x)$ evaluated at $x=1$

Comment: @ForeverMozart Is it ? How? I didn't see that.

Comment: $\operatorname{arctan}(x)$ does work. great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\arctan1=\frac11-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\dots$$

$$\arctan1=\beta$$

$$1=\tan\beta=\frac{\sin\beta}{\cos\beta}$$

$$\sin\beta=\cos\beta$$

$$\beta=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Hence, (2) is not rational, but (3) is.